# Device is not detected via MTP (TCL Idol X S950 phone)

Tags: android, mtp

I have just purchased a new TCL Idol X S950 phone and I'm figuring out some issue to make it visible on my system.

This phone uses Android 4.2.2 and I guess this is the cause of the issue: my previous phone with android 4.1 was correctly displayed in nautilus/dolphin (using `mtpfs`).

Now I have tried to install `mtp-tools`, but nothing has changed.

`lsusb` gives me that list (T&A Mobile Phones should be my phone).

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bbb:0168 T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b80 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp.
```

`dmesg` gives me this output:

```
15780.855333] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[15780.874336] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=0168
[15780.874348] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[15780.874354] usb 3-2: Product: TCL S950
[15780.874359] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: TCT
[15780.874364] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: FESKMRSOYLW8RKSK
```

Comment: This is issue very unlikely to be related to the Android version on your phone, but the libmtp version on your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Include your device in libmtp source code

You can try to include your device in the libmtp source code and build libmtp from source.

Install mtp-tools and optionally the checkinstall package:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools libusb-dev checkinstall
sudo mtp-detect
```

Take note to VID and PID numbers, example:

- VID 22b8
- PID 2e82

Download the latest libmtp source from the [project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/files/libmtp/). At the time of writing the version was 1.1.6, so this is would be an example:

```
wget http://downloads.sorceforge.net/project/libmtp/1.1.6/libmtp-1.1.6.tar.gz
tar xvf libmtp-1.1.6.tar.gz
cd libmtp-1.1.6
```

Add an entry to your in device in the source:

```
gedit src/music-players.h
```

Example:

```
{ "Motorola", 0x22b8, "Moto G (XT1032)", 0x2e82,  DEVICE_FLAGS_ANDROID_BUGS }
```

**Note,** pay attention to the trailing commas (`,`) in the file like this:

```
[...]

{ "Motorola", 0x22b8, "Moto X (XT1058)", 0x2e63,
      DEVICE_FLAGS_ANDROID_BUGS },

{ "Motorola", 0x22b8, "Moto G (XT1032)", 0x2e82,
      DEVICE_FLAGS_ANDROID_BUGS },

{ "Motorola", 0x22b8, "Droid Maxx (XT1080)", 0x2e67,
      DEVICE_FLAGS_ANDROID_BUGS },

[...]
```

Now configure, build and install (`checkinstall` is recommended over `make install`) the patched version:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Reboot and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Iview i700. Here's what I did to resolve it.

'lsusb' before plugging and after plugging.

After the android device appeared on the list:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 8087:0a15 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10d5:5a08 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I edited the rules with

`sudo gedit  /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`

and added the numbers for my pad **(yours may be different)**

```
# Iview i700 Tablet
ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", ATTR{idProduct}=="0a15", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

I also edited android rules with `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

and again added the numbers for my pad.

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", ATTR{idProduct}=="0a15", MODE="0666"
```

And finally I unplugged the pad and issued the command `sudo service udev restart`

plugged back in and it was immediately recognized in Nautilus with the pad on the MTP setting 
[image: MTPi700]

Note: (PTP worked previously but only opened up Shotwell)

Source: Based in part on a howto by writemem at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702 including only the steps I used ( I skipped 1, 2 and 7 as unnecessary)