# Gnome in ubuntu is unable to recognise Android phone connected to pc

Tags: gnome, android

I have just started using gnome. My android phone when connected to pc via USB, charges but I can't find the phone anywhere in the gnome.

any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

```
speedious@monu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:930b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 2717:ff48  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


speedious@monu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial



speedious@monu:~$ mtp-detect | grep idVendor
Device 0 (VID=2717 and PID=ff48) is a Xiaomi Mi-2s (MTP).
   idVendor: 2717
speedious@monu:~$ mtp-detect | grep idProduct
Device 0 (VID=2717 and PID=ff48) is a Xiaomi Mi-2s (MTP).
   idProduct: ff48
```

Comment: In your phone, you're supposed to select the desired mode, MTP or PTP, the latter being for photos only and the former for everything else.If your phone doesn't recognize it's connected to a computer (not just a wall charger) it seldom is a OS problem.

Comment: I have enabled those options but still gnome doesn't recognise it. I didn't have this problem in unity.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post. It would likely also be helpful to know what android phone you have.

Comment: Please also [edit] the output of `mtp-detect` into your post. If you don't have it, install it with `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools`

Comment: Possibly Related:https://askubuntu.com/a/586301/225694

Comment: @ElderGeek any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest that you visit the answer that I linked as related in my previous comment and substitute your VID, PID, and device name for the ones I used there. I think the part you are missing begins with `sudo gedit  /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up terminal and type the command `lsusb` and post the output here.

Try to make the Android phone to list as MTP (media share) / PTP (Android as a camera) / data instead of charging only by simply tapping at the charging like notification and see if its recognized or not.

Update:

1. Make a copy of `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` , incase you dont have one then simply create one.In this case you need to change the permission once the file is created `sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
2. In the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file, add this line:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2717", ATTR{idProduct}=="ff48", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
   ```

Using any editor like vi,vim,nano,sublime,etc. Make sure its in `sudo` mode.

3. Save the file and try connecting android again. It should work.

Note :

- `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`  happens to be a system file so make sure to copy it so that any tinkering gone wrong can be fixed by replacing the main file with the copied one.

  - `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`   can only be edited in  `sudo` mode
  - You can add more Android device in your udev rules by cloning the repository [Android Udev rules](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules)

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: seems like there is no value for usb mod switch . So adding a new rule to udev can fix it.

Comment: could  you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: can't find 51-android.rules inside rules.d neither can I create one.

Comment: you need to be in sudo mode to edit the file.You can use vi,nano,etc editor to do the same

Comment: I have edited my post so that  you can easily create one using `sudo` and can also get a huge repository of android.rules in case you need one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65752/discussion-between-monu-suri-and-siddharth).

Answer (score 0):

A USB menu should pop up as soon as you connect your phone. Select the **MTP** connection. Then mount the phone as any other drive.

Don't forget to unmount the phone from Ubuntu before you either disconnect the cable or change that MTP option in that menu.